# Error:The method dataSource(DataSource) is undefined for the type EntityManagerFactoryBuilder

Tags: database, spring-boot, eclipse, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to connect two databases(MSSQL server and H2db) using springboot with spring data jpa and hibernate
I have created two configuration files
but getting error in configuration file.

Error:The method dataSource(DataSource) is undefined for the type EntityManagerFactoryBuilder

at return builder.dataSource(db2DataSource()) point

DbOneConfig

```
package com.examle.demo.config.h2db;


import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder; 
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
//to active transaction and services
@EnableTransactionManagement 
@EnableJpaRepositories(
      entityManagerFactoryRef = "db1EntityManagerFactory",
      transactionManagerRef = "db1TransactionManager",
      basePackages = { "package com.example.h2db.repo" } //for repository
    )
public class DbOneConfig {
 
//datasource
@Bean         //indicates creating the Object here
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix ="db1.datasource")
public DataSource db1DataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();//build method returns the Object ,
    //create method internally builds the datasource here
}
//EntityManagerFactory
@Primary
@Bean(name = "db1EntityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean db1EntityManagerFactory(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier("db1DataSource") DataSource db1DataSource
        ) {
    //HashMap<String, Object>properties = new HashMap<>();
    //properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","create");
    //properties.put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
    return  builder
                    .dataSource(db1DataSource)     //getting error on this line
                    .packages("com.eaxample.demo.model.h2db")
                    .build();
}

 //TXManager
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager db1TransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("db1EntityManagerFactory")
        //read object from the container
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory
        ) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have imported org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder and you should import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder.